# zabbix issues didn't include IP address?

Tags: zabbix

[comparison picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu7Hw.png)

like picture

the first zabbixserver log   sendSMSlog

$2=PROBLEM: Free disk space is less than 20% on volume /boot       $3= ZQDBA: Free disk space is less than 20% on volume /boot

the second zabbix server log  snedSMSlog

$2=PROBLEM: 1xxxxx.254  Free disk space is less than 20% on volume /boot       $3= ZQ: 1xxxx254  Free disk space is less than 20% on volume /boot

the first server Cant't get the hostIP in issue

thx

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be caused by the trigger configuration - one of them is using `{HOST.HOST}` or `{HOST.NAME}` macro in the trigger name, the other is not.